# Dynamically adding and removing widgets on Tablesorter

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

At the start of jquery loading - a tablesorter is initialized using only zebra widget:

```
$('.tablesorter-blue').tablesorter({
   widthFixed : true,           
   usNumberFormat : false,
   sortReset      : true,
   sortRestart    : true,
   widgets        : ['zebra']
});
```

through a button click I add a 'scroller' widget dynamically:

```
$('.tablesorter-blue').trigger('applyWidgets', true);
$('.tablesorter-blue')[0].config.widgets = ['scroller'];
```

that works ok, as it added the scroller widget, and also retain the previous widget (zebra).

My problem is which I'm currently stuck with is to remove again the scroller widget from the tablesorter and just retain the zebra widget. I already try these codes, but failed:

from the documentation - refreshwidget - http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#refreshwidgets:

```
//remove all widgets
$('.tablesorter-blue').trigger('refreshWidgets', true, true);
$('.tablesorter-blue')[0].config.widgets = [];

//re-add widget (zebra)
$('.tablesorter-blue').trigger('applyWidgets', true);
$('.tablesorter-blue')[0].config.widgets = ['zebra'];
```

This is the error reported:

```
TypeError: $(...)[0].config is undefined
```

UPDATE:
code added as given by @mottie - no effect the scroller still there

```
        $('.tablesorter-blue').closest('.tablesorter-scroller').find('.tablesorter-scroller-header').remove();
        $('.tablesorter-blue')
            .unwrap()
            .find('.tablesorter-filter-row').removeClass('hideme').end()
            .find('thead').show().css('visibility', 'visible');
        $('.tablesorter-blue')[0].config.isScrolling = false;
```

***UPDATE: 10 FEB, 2014***

Problem is now solved thanks to mottie for the widget-scroller.js update. I already updated my code with the new version.

As shown in the demo, this is my code to add and remove scroller widget:

```
//initialize tablesorter
//THE TRICK IS TO PUT IN A VARIABLE LOL, SO THAT IT CAN BE UPDATED LATER :D
//THANKS AGAIN MOTTIE
var $tblSorter = $('.tablesorter-blue').tablesorter({               
    widgets: ['zebra'] //no SCROLLER
});

//Code for adding scroller
$tblSorter.trigger('refreshWidgets', [true, true]); //REMOVE ALL WIDGETS
$tblSorter[0].config.widgets = ['zebra', 'scroller']; //ADD ZEBRA & SCROLLER
$tblSorter.trigger('applyWidgets');

//Code for removing scroller
$tblSorter.trigger('refreshWidgets', [true, true]); //REMOVE ALL WIDGETS
$tblSorter[0].config.widgets = ['zebra']; //REMOVE THE SCROLLER, RETAIN ZEBRA ONLY
$tblSorter.trigger('applyWidgets');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else stumbling upon this question in the future, since v2.25 there is a "removeWidget" method built into TableSorter.

```
$('.tablesorter').trigger('removeWidget', ['scroller'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sad to say that the scroller widget needs a lot of work, and bug fixes; this includes removing it from the table while refreshing widgets.

I answered a similar question describing how to [remove the scroller here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333402/tablesorter-filter-and-scroller-widget-update/21338981#21338981). This is the relevant code you need:

```
// remove scroller widget completely
$table.closest('.tablesorter-scroller').find('.tablesorter-scroller-header').remove();
$table
    .unwrap()
    .find('.tablesorter-filter-row').removeClass('hideme').end()
    .find('thead').show().css('visibility', 'visible');
$table[0].config.isScrolling = false;
```

---

Update: Oh, I did notice that in the code above, the parameters passed to the "refreshWidgets" were not wrapped in brackets. It should look like this:

```
$('.tablesorter-blue').trigger('refreshWidgets', [true, true]);
```

[here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/2025/), with a slightly modified version of the remove widget code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#table1').tablesorter();

    var $table2 = $('#table2').tablesorter({
        widgets : ['scroller']
    });

    $('button').click(function(){
        var widgets = $table2[0].config.widgets;
        $table2.trigger('refreshWidgets', [true, true]);
        $table2[0].config.widgets = $.inArray('scroller', widgets) >= 0 ?
            [] : ['scroller'];
        $table2.trigger('applyWidgets');
    });

});
```

Comment: no effect, the scroller still there, I updated my question with your code. Dunno maybe I use it incorrectly

Comment: when I test it, the scroller is gone for a second, and then refresh into the tablesorter again

Comment: I remove this code - $('.tablesorter-blue')[0].config.isScrolling = false; and it works, the scroller is gone but when I click the button to toggle again the scroller, it's not working anymore

Comment: I'll wait until a stable scroller widget available for scroll toggle, right now I'm using two tablesorter, one with scroller and the other without - thanks anway for the answer

Comment: Oops, I told you to wrap the refreshWidget parameters in brackets and even I didn't do it in the code above LOL... updated now.

Comment: I already updated the scroller widget code from your demo and it's working now for me, thanks. I put my solution at the end of my question. Thanks again for the guides :D